# Программа с библиотекой dayjs выдает ошибку в консоли браузера

Tags: javascript, npm

На данный момент учу пакетные менеджеры и в качестве практического примера решил установить через npm библиотеку "dayjs".

Я убедился, что 'dayjs' установлен в мой проект с помощью npm, и использую атрибут type="module" в теге script в HTML-файле.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Current Time</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
    <script type="module" src="/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

А мой JavaScript-код в 'script.js' довольно прост:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
const currentRegionElement = document.getElementById('current-region')
const currentTimeElement = document.getElementById('current-time')
const currentDateElement = document.getElementById('current-date')

function updateInfo() {
    const currentTime = dayjs().format('HH:mm:ss')
    const currentRegion = dayjs().format('Z')
    const currentDate = dayjs().format('YYYY-MM-DD')

    currentRegionElement.textContent = `Region: UTC${currentRegion}`
    currentTimeElement.textContent = `Current Time: ${currentTime}`
    currentDateElement.textContent = `Today's Date: ${currentDate}`
}

setInterval(updateInfo, 1000)

updateInfo()
```

Лог ошибки:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Спецификатор «dayjs» являлся голым спецификатором, но не был переназначен на что-либо. Связанные спецификаторы модуля должны начинаться с «./», «../» или «/».
```

Я пробовал различные решения, найденные в Интернете, но так и не смог решить эту проблему. Может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне понять, почему я получаю эту ошибку и как ее исправить?

Любые рекомендации и предложения будут очень признательны. Спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте импортировать `import dayjs from 'dayjs/esm'`